# Structure of a multiplayer card game (Hearts) with Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-computing, multiplayer, middleware

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best practice for implementing a "Hearts" multiplayer game with Java RMI.

**Here's what I thought so far:**

- A remote interface with the methods for the common tasks requested by the players (deal cards for each player, passing cards to other players, play a card, etc).
- The server would contain 4 Player objects containing their cards, current effects (pursuing the 2 of clubs, being allowed or not to play heart cards into the game, etc) and the variables defining the current game state (cards already played, current suit being used, if heart cards can be played, etc).
- The client instances would only deal with the GUI (which changes based on the results provided by the remote method calls)

**What I still have no idea:**

- After a Player plays a card, how do I communicate with the other clients efficiently to update their GUI right after the action was done? (I only found examples where the client call server to do something, not the reverse)
- Should I implement each Player object as remote objects too? Or just regular objects into the server instance?
- Is it possible to control each client state (playing, waiting for other players, end of round,...) using threads? If so, how can I do this?
- Any suggestions on how the application structure could be better are welcome too.

Comment: Look at cajo.  Makes the network part simpler.